# ASP.NET MVC 4 Back Button -> Form Submit -> 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-4, back-button

Having some odd behavior I'd love some feed back on as I can't seem to find any details on this sort of thing anywhere...

**Setup:**
Using ASP.NET MVC 4 and VS 2010, I have created a corporate directory application with a search page and a details page that displays a corporate tree based on the search selection.

The search page is very basic and using ajax.beginform it returns a list of people back based on the criteria selected.  After clicking on the person you get a "tree" showing that individual, their supervisor and any subordinates.

**Problem**
The user searches for someone, clicks on their result, sees the tree.  When they click the back button (with or without performing any other action on the tree view) they are returned to the search screen.  The criteria they entered is there but the results are not (as I would expect).  If they click search or hit the enter key, the user then receives a 404 page not found error...

**What I've Tried**
From the things I've read, I've been focusing on possible solutions revolving around the cache, I've tried expiring the page or setting the page for no-cache but that has not seemed to resolve the issue.

**CODE**

Search View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PersonList", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace }))
{

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)<br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)<br />

        <input type="submit" value="Search" />

        <div id="results">
        </div>
}
```

Block that gets plopped in for the search results. This is a partial view that is reused for the tree view as well.  That is why you'll see that the link at the top of the block is in a conditional.  If the link is to be used from the search page, it's an html link that forces a full page change.  If you're already on the tree view though, navigation is done via ajax.  The 404 error I'm receiving occurs without navigating at all on the tree view page:

```
<div id="p@{ Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id); }" class="personCard">
    <img class="personImg" id="img@{ Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id); }" src="@Url.Content("~/Photos")/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)" />
    <div>
        @if(ViewBag.IsForSearch == null) {
            @Ajax.ActionLink(this.Model.FullName, "PersonHierarchy", new { id = this.Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "tree" })
        } else {
            @Html.ActionLink(this.Model.FullName, "Person", new { id = this.Model.Id })
        }
        @if(this.Model.TeamSize > 0) {
            @:&nbsp;(
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TeamSize)
            @:)
        }
        <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MailLocationCode), @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WorkNumber) &nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ExtensionForDisplay)<br />
        @if (this.Model.CellNumber.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            @:Cell:
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CellNumber)
            @:<br />
        }
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    </div>
</div>
```

Response from Server:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

**EDIT:** 
**This appears to be specific to IE 9 (in all modes).  This behavior does not happen in Chrome and the search form resubmits perfectly after using the back button...**

Comment: Look at the HTML generated by the Ajax.BeginForm helper both before and after you press the back button.  Judging by the fact that the submit is posting to your server root, the Ajax.BeginForm helper is probably not working correctly(i.e. not generating the correct html) after you press the back button.

Comment: You would be correct, on the initial hit to the page there is all of the data-bind statements, etc, on the form tag.  On navigating back to the page, there are none of those statements, just an action and a method.  **Interestingly enough** this appears to be specific to IE 9 (in all modes).  Chrome handles the back button action without issue and the form submits again as it should...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK...I seem to have found the answer:

To recap, specifically in IE 9 when using ASP.NET MVC Ajax, using the back button to navigate back to a page that has a ajax form on it and trying to submit that form results in a 404 error.

I initially looked into various cache solutions to try to force IE to realize that the page needed to be "reloaded" (even though Chrome and other browsers had no issue with making the form work again when using the back button).  This apparently was the correct path to go down but unfortunately I didn't get far enough.  The solution ends up being setting the OutputCache for the controller action (or to the entire controller) to:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Adding that annotation to the action in the controller or to the controller class as a whole resolved the problem...thanks IE...

**For further information on this, I refer to my source:**
http://dougwilsonsa.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/disabling-ie9-ajax-response-caching-asp-net-mvc-3-jquery/

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using developer tools [F12] , Fiddler, Firebug, etc to see what the request is that is returning the 404 error message?  By determining what request is returning the 404 you can probably figure out why the request is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, and I should have included this in my original post. Once you click back and then try to click search again the post is going to: http://localhost:47651/  which would be the root of the app and not the controller/action.  It's sort of like the bindings for the ajax form are not being re-applied, but I'm not sure since this is back-button interaction how I would go about fixing that.

Comment: Updated my original question to include the 404 response indicating the url it's posting to...